# In the manga, how did Asako contact Ushio from within the sea serpent?

Tags: ushio-to-tora

In episode 6 of the *Ushio to Tora* anime, Asako and a boy she meets at the beach (Tatsuya) find themselves swallowed by some sort of giant sea serpent monstrosity. In the anime, Asako calls her grandparents' beach house using her cell phone, and that's how Ushio learns that she's in trouble.

But the manga was written back in the early '90s, before cell phones were commonplace (the anime has been relieved of some of the trappings of the '90s [much as *Parasyte* was] in the interest of appealing to modern audiences). How did this scene play out there? How did Ushio find out what had happened to Asako and Tatsuya?

Answer (score 2):

In both the manga and anime, Tatsuya had a precious gift from his mother.  In the anime, it was referred to as a toy phone.  In the manga, it was a functioning walkie talkie (referred to as *transceiver* in the English translation).  There just happened to be someone on the beach with another transceiver who was listening on the right channel.  Asako's call for help was heard by Ushio.

What I found difficult to understand is why Asako's plea was even needed as part of the plot.  The sea-protector yokai had already informed Ushio that Tora needed his help and had been swallowed by a giant serpent.  That could have been sufficient cause for Ushio to help.